# How to find the number of different ways in which a candidate can make his selection if he has to select at least 2 subjects from each group

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Ques.)**
For an examination, a candidate has to select 7 subjects from 3 different groups A, B, C, which contain 4, 5, 6 subjects, respectively. Find the number of different ways in which a candidate can make his selection if he has to select at least 2 subjects from each group.

**My approach**

At first I selected 2 subjects each from all the three groups in $(^4C_2).(^5C_2).(^6C_2)$ ways and then selected 1 more subject from 9 remaining subject in $^9C_1$ ways .Therefore toatal no. of ways came out to be $(^4C_2).(^5C_2).(^6C_2).(^9C_1)$ i.e. 8100

But in book its written 2700.
Can you please find out the error.

Comment: Your method overcounts, as you don't distinguish between the courses you choose initially and those you choose a the end.  Better to sum over the three choices for the group that contains the extra subject.

Comment: With a little effort you can salvage your method:  As only one group contains three chosen subjects, you are counting each solution three times.  So, just divide by $3$.  Should say, however, that usually this method can't be fixed so easily.

Comment: @ lulu thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

you can

- select A1 and A2 from group A, and in the end select A3 from group A
- or: select A2 and A3 from group A, and in the end select A1 from group A
- or: select A1 and A3 from group A, and in the end select A2 from group A

these three possibilities are the same, but you count them separately. Thats why you are off by a factor of 3.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Say the first group is comprised of persons $A,B,C,D$. You choose $1$ of the $4 \choose 2$ possibilities, say $\{A,B\}$. In your last step say you happen to choose person $C$ from this group. So in total you’ve chosen $\{A,B,C\}$ from this group. But the same outcome would happen if you had chosen $\{A,C\}$ in the first step, and $B$ in the last step, or $\{B,C\}$ and $A$. This happens for every choice in your computation. So just divide the number you found by $3$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes.